# Develop Laravel Package locally with path repository is not working

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have a Laravel app, that use a plugin of mine : "xoco70/kendo-tournaments"

So, to develop it, I added it in a packages/ folder in root of app.

Now, in my composer.json, I used path, to point the local rep, and not to have to go through composer ( and have to version it for each comma I change) :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "xoco70/kendo-tournaments": "dev-master"

    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/packages/xoco70/kendo-tournaments"
        }
    ],   
}
```

Thing is it doesn't work, when I try to `composer install` / `update`, it doesn't update the vendor folder.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: does there any errors?

Comment: Are you getting any feedback at all? Is your repo being cloned, symlinked or anything? Composer should provide some kind of feedback. If nothing happens you could try clearing your composer cache. One thing you could also still try is to use a relative path.

Comment: have you tried `composer update xoco70/kendo-tournaments --lock` ?

Comment: op! no update at all no errors. Do I need to commit, or just adding a change in packages/... will deploy the changes? composer update xoco70/kendo-tournaments --lock is not doing any thing. [composer clearcache` not working neither :(

Comment: even if I put a wrong path, it doesn't tell me anything....

Comment: do I need to put a version locally in my composer.json?

Comment: The url should be `"url": "./packages/xoco70/kendo-tournaments"` (with dot) if the packages folder is in root of your app

Comment: :( it still says : Nothing to install or update

Answer (score 1):

I could make it work

first I added the symlink option:

```
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "package/xoco70/laravel-tournaments",
      "options": {
        "symlink": true
      }
    }
  ],
```

Then `composer update`

If it still doesn't work, delete your vendor package and run `composer update again`

composer should output this:

```
  - Installing xoco70/laravel-tournaments (dev-master): Symlinking from package/xoco70/laravel-tournaments
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `composer init` from `/packages/xoco70/kendo-tournaments` in and use `xoco70/kendo-tournaments` for the name of the package as well as that packages autoload settings for your project composer to pick it up.

Comment: I already did composer init, my package is already working on packagist. I also autoload it on my project

Comment: Try running `composer clear-cache` and then `composer update` after your cache is cleared.